# Efficient database model for points system?

Tags: sql, optimization

I'm trying to add a very simple points system to a site. In my SQL database, there is a table for awarding points, since admins can increase a user's points by any amount, along with a rationale for the points increase. So, simplified a little, this table contains the # of points awarded, rationale and userid for each time an admin awards points. So far so good.

However, there are 10 usergroups on the site that compete for highest total points. The number of points for a single usergroup can easily hit 15 000 total, as there are already more than 10 000 members of the site (admittedly, most are inactive). I want to have a leaderboard to show the competing usergroups and their total scores, but I'm worried that when implementing the system, summing the points will take too long to do each time. Here's the question: at what level (if any) should I save the points aggregate in the database? Should I have a field in the user table for total points per user and sum those up on the fly for the usergroup leaderboard? Or should I have an aggregate field for each usergroup that I update each times points are added to a single user? Before actually implementing the system, I'd like to have a good idea of how long it will take to sum these up on the fly, since a bad implementation will affect thousands of users, and I don't have much practical experience with large databases.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Honestly, your aggregates will still likely compute in less than a second with less than 10k rows -you should leave your operational database atomic and just store each point transaction and compute the aggregates when you query. If you really wanted to, you could precompute your aggregates into a materialized view, but I really don't think you'd need to.

You could create a materialized view with the clause

```
   refresh fast start with sydate
     next sysdate + 1/24
```

-To have it refresh hourly.

You wouldn't have real-time aggregate data (it could be off by an hour), but it could increase the performance of your aggregate queries by quite a bit if the data gets huge. As your data is now, I wouldn't even bother with it though -- your performance *should* be alright.

edit: not sure why I'm being down-voted. I think this is a better solution than storing aggregates in tables.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your hardware but summing thousands of rows should be no problem. In general though, you should avoid summing all the user scores except when you absolutely need to. I would recommend adding in a rolup table that will store the total score for each group and then run a cron nightly that will validate the total scores (basically do the summation and then store the absolutely correct values).

I suggest adding in your table that logs points awarded and reason for the award. Also, store the summed scores per user separately and update it at the same time your insert into the logging table and another table with the total score per group. That should work well at your activity level. You could also do asynchronous updates of the total group scores if it is too contentious but it should be fine.